# Why can't I see some close reasons?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Today I've realized that when voting for closing questions, some of them have have an account for some reasons I can't see. For instance:

[image: Screenshot 1]

So I read that question, see that it lacks sufficient information and I'm voting for its closing. In the first menu I see there are 3 votes:

[image: Screenshot 2]

But once I click on the "Offtopic" submenu I can see just 2 votes:

[image: Screenshot 3]

I can't see the third reason which I assume has only one vote (*code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved*). The same I've noticed for this one:

> off-topic: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Why is that I can't see those reasons as options nor the votes for them?

Comment: It's a closevote that has been given before the new reasons came into the system (and some old ones dissapeared). The reasons are gone but the vote that had been cast stayed - but can't be displayed because it's not linked to a reason.

Comment: Ok, probably I'm seeing some pretty old questions from the Close queue, it's just today I noticed it, though. If you wish to write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe something changed with the recent CVQ change that affected old posts floating up. I'll take a quick look around to find a duplicate instead, I've seen a few pass by today already.

Comment: Might be, I just moderated a `Nov 13 '13 at 13:53` question with the same issue.